# using jquery datatables plugin in jsf application and data should be populated from jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jsf, richfaces

i am using jsf 1.2 with Rich faces, but now the requirement is to change the existing pages(Tables for now) to jquery supported tables(DataTables plugin) because the Rich faces are having performance issues and also we want to do it for extra features.

- what should be the right way, currently trying use the DataTables and making an ajax call to a Servlet for server side processing and returing JSON data to populate the table.

  - please suggest the suitable options to achieve these.

Thanking you all.

Comment: The method you mentioned is fine, you'll just need to convert the JSON into an Array or Arrays which is the rows.

Answer (score 1):

If your intended use is to have extreme amounts of table rows (10,000+) in single instances then Datatables with server side processing is the way to go.
Each time you click the pagination or filter it will make a new request to the server for fresh json data.

If however the amount of rows is somewhere between 200-10,000 i would use either the javascript array(which could be printed on page load), or the ajax Source option, These to options basically mean all the data is pushed to the client side on the initial datatables draw, but Datatables plugin will append/remove the rows the the dom when required.

The first option is just apply datatable object to a normal html table, which might be the fastest to impliment if you allready have the tables there. Due to the initial table row and cell creation, this is by far the least effective performance wise, and wouldnt recommend on tables with more than 200 or so rows.

For a better understanding just check the sources documentation on the right block of the homepage.
http://datatables.net/examples/

Comment: Thanks for your answer guys. I am very skeptical about the JSF Beans which have correct data so far. I have to covert these so that they return JSON objects. I am confused, what will be the use of JSF then, and don't you think that converting the beans to JSON objects is tedious. Please suggest your valuable inputs to clear my dilemma. Is this direction is right?